# Smooth movement of a point in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to programming in C# and might need some assistance with this problem I have encountered.
My point, playerposition has a very jerky movement due to the delay caused when holding down a key. Like this: e ...   e e e e e e e e ;)

How do you make it move around more smoothly, (getting rid of the delay?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace kek
{

    class player
    {
        Image Player;
        Point Playerposition = new Point(600, 200);
        Form1 game;
        public void playerinitialize(Form game)
        {
            this.game = (Form1)game;
            Player = Bitmap.FromFile("player.png");
            game.KeyDown += Game_KeyDown;
            game.KeyPress += Game_KeyPress;

        }

        private void Game_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar < 50)
            {
                Playerposition.Y -= 10;
            }

        }

        private void Game_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Player move on keypress
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            {
                Playerposition.Y -= 10;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                Playerposition.Y += 10;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                Playerposition.X -= 10;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                Playerposition.X += 10;
            }

            //Playerposition.Y -= GamePad.GetState(PLayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Left.Y;
            //Playerposition.Y += GamePad.GetState(PLayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Right.Y;

            //Playerposition.X -= GamePad.GetState(PLayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Left.X;
            //Playerposition.X += GamePad.GetState(PLayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Right.X;

        }
        public void Draw(Graphics graphics)
        {
            //on update

            graphics.DrawImage(Player, Playerposition);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step one is not to use WinForms for games...  Or at least change the entire concept of handling the game logic in the KeyDown event handler. You need a game loop that runs all the time, and variables that store which keys are (de)pressed. Read about double buffering and blitting if you want smooth animations.

Comment: Well you're moving it by 10 pixels each time, so obviously it won't be smooth.

Comment: Don't update the game state in the events, start an operation that starts an animation, eg changing the position of the item every X milliseconds. This holds even for business applications - don't update the bank account in the OnClick event, call a method in a class whose job is to update the bank account

Comment: WPF already supports animations and transitions, in *this* case you could specify that an item should move by X pixels in Y milliseconds. In general though, the game's state should be separated from the rendering code. That's just proper OOP

Comment: It is "jerky" because the key does not nearly repeat fast enough to provide smooth motion.  You need to use the KeyDown and KeyUp events to set a *bool* that indicates the key is down.  And then in your "game loop" (could be as simple as a 15 or 31 msec timer), you calculate a new position if the bool is true and draw the image at that position.  Now you animate at the frame rate instead of the keyboard repeat rate.

Comment: *Please* make sure you look at the text of the tags you add. `Movement` is marked as do not use and `smooth` is related to statistics or image processing. Removing those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it's better not to use WinForms for game dev. However it's not impossible to do something like what you want.

Key for your requirement is not to update the position within a key event. A basic game loop continuously does the following. First it would 'Update positions' and secondly it paints the new positions on screen.

So first we want to update the positions, but to do this we must know whether or not a key is pressed or not. One way of doing this is to capture key down and key up events and mark these in a keyboard map. Within the update we now only check if a key is down and accordingly update the position of the 'Player'.

Some time ago i just created a little demo project for fun. I'll share it with you. Hope it helps.

**Update:** Also when updating the movement take in consideration that the time between two draws can differ each time. So you should within the update determine the amount of movement should be added. See the Snake.UpdatePositions method ? I state that after 1 second the player should have moved 100 units (pixels). So i calculate the amount of displacement there would be according to the time between now and the last frame.

Make a Winform project called SmoothAnimationDemo and replace the code for the Form1.cs with the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SmoothAnimationDemo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // check every x frames, calculate fps, adjust x
        private readonly FrameInfo _frameInfo = new FrameInfo(DateTime.Now);
        private readonly List<Animation> _animations = new List<Animation>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DoubleBuffered = true;

            FrameInfoVisible = false; // Set to true if needed. 
            RegisterAnimation(new Snake(this));
        }

        public bool FrameInfoVisible { get; set; }

        public void RegisterAnimation(Animation animation)
        {
            _animations.Add(animation);
        }

        private int _skipframes = 1;

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            // Skip updating if needed.
            if (_skipframes > 0)
            {
                _skipframes--;
            }
            else
            {
                _frameInfo.Update();
                foreach (var animation in _animations)
                    animation.UpdatePositions(_frameInfo);

                _skipframes = 0; // adjust to skip frames or leave at 0 to not skip frames. 
            }

            // init drawing
            var gfx = e.Graphics;
            gfx.Clear(Color.Black);

            // draw each frame. 
            foreach (var animation in _animations)
            {
                animation.Draw(gfx);
                gfx.ResetTransform(); // in case the animation used transform methods.
            }

            // draw timer info on top
            if (FrameInfoVisible)
                _frameInfo.Draw(gfx);

            // wait till a certain time has passed before drawing again. 
            //Thread.Sleep(10);
            Invalidate(); // ensure new paint soon
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// abstract base class for animations.
    /// An animation contains two methods. First one used for updating animation data, eg positions.
    /// Second one used for drawing the data onto a graphics object.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class Animation : IDrawable, IAnimatable
    {
        public abstract void Draw(Graphics gfx);

        public abstract void UpdatePositions(FrameInfo frameInfo);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains info about our frames
    /// </summary>
    public class FrameInfo
    {
        public DateTime FirstFrameTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime PrevFrameTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime FrameTime { get; set; }
        public int FrameCount { get; set; }
        public double FramesPerSecond { get; set; }

        public FrameInfo(DateTime now)
        {
            FirstFrameTime = now;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            PrevFrameTime = FrameTime;
            FrameTime = DateTime.Now;
            FrameCount++;
            FramesPerSecond = 1000.0 / (FrameTime - PrevFrameTime).TotalMilliseconds;
        }

        public void Draw(Graphics gfx)
        {
            gfx.DrawString("Frame time", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
            gfx.DrawString(String.Format(": {0:hh:mm:ss.zzzz}", FrameTime - FirstFrameTime), SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, 70, 0);
            gfx.DrawString("Frame", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 16);
            gfx.DrawString(": " + FrameCount, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, 70, 16);
            gfx.DrawString("FPS", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 32);
            gfx.DrawString(": " + FramesPerSecond, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, 70, 32);
        }
    }

    internal interface IAnimatable
    {
        void UpdatePositions(FrameInfo frameInfo);
    }

    internal interface IDrawable
    {
        void Draw(Graphics gfx);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Animation module
    /// </summary>
    internal class Snake : Animation
    {
        public Snake(Control form)
        {
            form.KeyDown += form_KeyDown;
            form.KeyUp += form_KeyUp;
        }

        readonly Dictionary<Keys, bool> _keyMap = new Dictionary<Keys, bool>
        {
            { Keys.Up, false },
            { Keys.Down, false },
            { Keys.Left, false },
            { Keys.Right, false }
        };

        void form_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_keyMap.ContainsKey(e.KeyCode))
                _keyMap[e.KeyCode] = false;
        }

        void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_keyMap.ContainsKey(e.KeyCode))
                _keyMap[e.KeyCode] = true;
        }

        private PointF _headPos = new PointF(100.0f, 100.0f);

        public override void UpdatePositions(FrameInfo info)
        {
            // Ensure that the motion is moving at a 
            var speed = 100; // 100 units within 1 second
            var perc = (double)(info.FrameTime - info.PrevFrameTime).TotalMilliseconds / 1000;
            var displaceAmount = (float)(speed * perc);

            if (_keyMap[Keys.Up])
                _headPos.Y -= displaceAmount;
            if (_keyMap[Keys.Down])
                _headPos.Y += displaceAmount;
            if (_keyMap[Keys.Right])
                _headPos.X += displaceAmount;
            if (_keyMap[Keys.Left])
                _headPos.X -= displaceAmount;
        }

        public override void Draw(Graphics gfx)
        {
            gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            gfx.DrawString(String.Format("[{0},{1}]", _headPos.X, _headPos.Y), SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, 0.0f, 48.0f);
            gfx.DrawEllipse(Pens.White, _headPos.X, _headPos.Y, 10.0f, 10.0f);
        }
    }

}
```